# styling active element menu in flask

Tags: flask

i have following templates structure in flask:

```
templates/
  /posts
    list.html
  base.html
  index.html
```

my base.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>ITV</title>
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='css/main.css') }}">

    <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
    <script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

{%- block topbar -%}
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top" role="navigation">
      <!-- We use the fluid option here to avoid overriding the fixed width of a normal container within the narrow content columns. -->
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">САПР</a>
        </div>

        <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-8">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="active"><a href="/">Головна</a></li>
            <li><a href="/posts">Новини</a></li>
            <li><a href="/schedue">Розклад занять</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
      </div>
    </nav>
{%- endblock -%}

<div class="container">
    <div class="content">
        {% block page_header %}{% endblock %}
        {% block content %}{% endblock %}
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

i can render template, for example : render_template('posts/list.html'), which extends my base.html

my list.html:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block content %}

    Posts
{% endblock %}
```

How can i set active element menu in base.html

```
        <li class="active"><a href="/">Головна</a></li>
        <li><a href="/posts">Новини</a></li>
        <li><a href="/schedue">Розклад занять</a></li>
```

when i'm rendering list.html, and cant pass data directly into base.html?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

In Flask, the `request` variable is [available by default](http://flask.readthedocs.org/en/latest/templating/#standard-context) in templates, so you can simply check `request.path` in your `base.html` and adjust your links.

```
<li {% if request.path == '/' %}class="active"{% endif %}>
     <a href="/">Головна</a>
</li>
```

Comment: It is nicer to use `url_for` instead of just using the literal `'/'`. This way, if you ever change a routing endpoint, you'll only have to change it in one place. On the other hand, if you change the name of the method for that endpoint, modern IDEs (like PyCharm) will refactor the method name in the `url_for` call in the HTML template, as well.

Answer (score 1):

Can use a ternary also...just a bit shorter & nicer

```
<li {{ 'class="active"' if request.path == '/' else '' }}>
     <a href="/">Головна</a>
</li>
```